# Cannot find bing news search api resource in azure market place

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-marketplace

I could not find how to add "Bing News Search API v7" on Azure market place. I only found Bing Search, and obviously the keys did not work for the News end points (401 Unauthorized).

I know it sounds a little dumb, but its been a few days of trying to get these api keys without success.

FYI, I had a free trial on bing news v5, but it expired. I am trying to go for a pay as you go subscription. Can some one please point me in the right direction

[Followed the link, this is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4v33.png)[I have the subscription for bing search api, but I get unauthorized when I use these keys, very weird.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjcfK.png)

Comment: I am sure this is Tier S2, which doesn't have news search offering. You need to have access keys from one of these tiers: S1, S5, or S8.

Comment: Did this fix the issue or you are still getting 401?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it from **Azure Portal** by clicking on **Create Resource** => Search **Bing Search V7 APIs** => **Create**.

[image]

You can access it from **Azure Portal** by clicking on **All Services** => **Marketplace** => Search **Bing Search V7 APIs** => **Create**

[image]

**Note:** The free trial is sufficient for this quickstart. You need the access key provided when you activate your free trial, or you may use a paid subscription key from your Azure dashboard.

For more details, refer "[Bing New Search Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-news-search/)"

Comment: please see my attached screen shots. I have the bing search api, I try to use the keys, but I get unauthorized for https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news endpoint. it works for https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=test endpoint

Comment: Although it did not fix my specific problem yet, I'll mark this as an answer.

Comment: It depends on which tier your keys are meant for. If you are having keys for S2, they won't work with news search. You need to have keys for S1, S5, or S8. More info on this pricing page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/search-api/web/.

Answer (score 0):

It's here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-news-search-api/.

You can get **free access keys** for v7 by clicking on "Try Bing News Search API" from this page. The **pay-as-you-go subscription** can be purchased from: https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CognitiveServicesBingSearch-v7. Alternately, you can click on "Portal" on the above page for buying keys.